# Using harsh language

Tags: discussion, flagging

I am not crazy about when people make comments like "please don't suggest that stupid Quicken". Lots of people use it and like it. Should i edit/report this kind of post?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you should!

While the sentiment of "please don't suggest Quicken" is fine, adding loaded, argumentative language like "stupid" does not help produce better answers.

I usually edit things like that to make them more conducive to civil responses.

Comment: Flagging such posts IMHO is a more appropriate approach. That way they know that the community does not encourage it. Plus, if they learn it then we don't need to waste our time editing such posts.

Comment: @monster per [the faq](http://money.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) editing is a standard fixture of the site and everyone is encouraged to make edits.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Jeff. Not so much that I am offended by slights against Quicken. However, I like to soften the tone sometimes on things like this with edits so that it doesn't turn into a battle in the comments.

That said, I probably wouldn't go so far to report it if I didn't have edit permissions unless there was already an altercation ramping up.

Comment: I think everyone has edit permissions now.   If you are under a certain rep, you just make edit "Suggestions" that get reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

The word 'stupid' doesn't really bother me.   But if people are using words that may cause our site to get banned by some kind of work filter, then that is definitely a problem (i.e. curse words).  I personally don't give a rat's **** :) but I don't want some parental filter to start banning *.stackexchange.com